# How to generate 256-AES CBC key with PKCS5 padding key in Dart

Tags: flutter, encryption, dart, aes

I need to figure out how to generate a random 256 AES CBC key with PKCS5 padding in Dart for my Flutter project. I've been able to accomplish it in Java using this:

```java
    public static SecretKey generateSecretKey() {
        KeyGenerator generator;
        try {
            generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            generator.init(256); // The AES key size in number of bits (256)

            return generator.generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In dart I've gotten as far as this (broken/unfinished code) using PointyCastle

```dart
  static generateSecretKey() {
    AESFastEngine aes = AESFastEngine();
    KeyParameter keyParameter = KeyParameter();
    aes.init(true, keyParameter);
    CBCBlockCipher cbc = CBCBlockCipher(aes);
  }
```

I'm using RSA 4096 keys for exchanging the AES 256 key. In the client side, I only use the public key for encrypting the generated AES key

Comment: Keys don't have the concept of padding associated with them. In the call `KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`  Java must be simply ignoring everything after the `AES` part because none of it makes sense. `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` only makes sense inside of `Cipher.getInstance()`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I just copied and pasted the ""AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" from my cipher code

Comment: I'm not familiar with PointyCastle but BouncyCastle doesn't seem to have a method to *generate* AES keys. You have generate them yourself using your platform's cryptographically secure random number generator and then supply this to the `KeyParameter` constructor.

Comment: How would I do that exactly? Use platform-specific code like https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?

Comment: Apparently dart provides this for you:[https://www.scottbrady91.com/Dart/Generating-a-Crypto-Random-String-in-Dart](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Dart/Generating-a-Crypto-Random-String-in-Dart)

Comment: pointycastle provides a Fortuna random number generator. An aes 256 bit key is exactly that: 256 random bits i.e. 32 bytes. You'll need an IV too, of course. It's rare to randomly generated an AES key, of course, as it has to be known by both ends. Normally it's derived by some key derivation algorithm. Consider updating the question with more details.

Comment: I'm using RSA keys for exchanging the AES key. @James Reinstate Monica Polk's answer seems to work how I want it, though I haven't tested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[@James Reinstate Monica Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/james-reinstate-monica-polk)

> Apparently dart provides this for you: https://www.scottbrady91.com/Dart/Generating-a-Crypto-Random-String-in-Dart

This seems to be a good solution for generating an AES 256 bit key.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt)